# Change player sprite on key press

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, monogame

I've been getting into monogame recently and I came across a problem.

I've loaded a player sprite and I've got movement working, but what I want to do is change the sprite when I press right/left. I want the player ship to lean left/right according to the key press.

This is what my current code looks like, as you can see, I've attempted to achieve the desired effect with if statement but I wasn't successful.

```
    class Player
    {
        public Texture2D PlayerTexture; //Animation representing the layer
        public Texture2D moveLeft;
        public Texture2D moveRight;
        public Vector2 Position;    //Position of the Player relative to the upper left side of the screen
        public bool Active; //State of the player
        public int Health;  //Amount of hit points the player has
        public int Width { get { return PlayerTexture.Width; } }    //Get width of the player ship
        public int Height { get { return PlayerTexture.Height; } }  //Get height of the player ship

        //Keyboard states used to determine key presses
        KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;
        KeyboardState previousKeyboardState;

        //Mouse states used to track Mouse button press
        MouseState currentMouseState;
        MouseState previousMouseState;

        float playerMoveSpeed;

        //Player moving left or right
        bool movingLeft;
        bool movingRight;

        public void Initialize(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
        {
            PlayerTexture = texture;
            Position = position;    //Set the starting position of the player around the middle of the screen and to the back
            Active = true;  //Set the player to be active
            Health = 100;   //Set the player health

            //Set a constant player move speed
            playerMoveSpeed = 8.0f;
        }

        public void PmovingLeft(Texture2D pmoveleft, Vector2 position)
        {
            moveLeft = pmoveleft;
            Position = position;
        }

        public void PmovingRight(Texture2D pmoveright, Vector2 position)
        {
            moveRight = pmoveright;
            Position = position;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            //Save the previous state of the keyboard so we can determine single key presses
            previousKeyboardState = currentKeyboardState;

            //Read the current state of the keyboard and store it
            currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
        }

        public void UpdatePlayer(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            //Keyboard controls

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                Position.X -= playerMoveSpeed;
                movingLeft = true;
            }
            else { movingLeft = false; }
            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                Position.X += playerMoveSpeed;
                movingRight = true;
            }
            else { movingRight = false; }
            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                Position.Y -= playerMoveSpeed;
            }
            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            {
                Position.Y += playerMoveSpeed;
            }

            //Make sure that the player does not go out of bounds
            Position.X = MathHelper.Clamp(Position.X, 0, Game1.screenWidth - Width);
            Position.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(Position.Y, 0, Game1.screenHeight - Height);
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {


            if (movingLeft)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(moveLeft, Position, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
            }
            else { spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTexture, Position, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f); }
            if (movingRight)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(moveRight, Position, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
            }
            else { spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTexture, Position, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f); }
            }         
        }
```

What this code does is move the player left/right but the player sprite does not change correctly. If anyone can help me resolve this issue, it would be fantastic. Thanks in advance!

**Game1.cs (main game class) can be provided upon request**

Comment: What happens exactly when you press left / right? Can you also provide the code where you reference the Player class?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dealing with all of these bools, what I would do is make an Enum.

So you could have an Enum SpriteState with different states and then a variable to hold the currentSpriteState

```
 Enum SpriteState
 {
   Left,
   Right,
   Straight
 }

 SpriteState currentSpriteState = SpriteState.Straight;
```

An example of changing states

```
  //generic condition and state change
if (condition) 
{
 currentSpriteState = SpriteState.Left;
}
else if(condition)
{
 currentSpriteState = SpriteState.Right;
}
else currentSpriteState = SpriteState.Straight;
```

Then have a switch case in the Draw() based on the currentSpriteState

```
 switch(currentSpriteState)
{
  case SpriteState.Left:
   spriteBatch.Draw(moveLeft, Position, null, Color.White, 0f,
   Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
  break;

  case SpriteState.Right:
   spriteBatch.Draw(moveRight, Position, null, Color.White, 0f,
   Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
  break;

  case SpriteState.Straight:
   spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTexture, Position, null, Color.White, 0f,
   Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
  break;
}
```

Bools could technically work, but this is much cleaner and easy to read and might just solve your problem.